# problem with regular expression replacement

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, streamwriter

I'm trying to make a program to go through a lot of .sql files and replace names for example view_name to [dbo].[view_name]. So far it replaces most of the words, however if a name contains number in brackets like (3) or (7) and so on it wont replace anything within that file. I've provided the code below.

```
        FolderBrowserDialog fb = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fb.ShowDialog();

        string directory = fb.SelectedPath;

        if(directory != String.Empty)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(directory);
            FileInfo[] fiArray = di.GetFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < fiArray.Length; i++)
            {
                string result;
                //StreamReader
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(directory + "\\" + fiArray[i].ToString()))
                {
                    string temp = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    string tempNameExtens = fiArray[i].Name;
                    string tempNameNoExtens = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fiArray[i].Name);
                    MessageBox.Show(tempNameNoExtens);


                    string pattern = "\\s" + tempNameNoExtens;
                    string replace = " [dbo].[" + tempNameNoExtens + "]";

                    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
                    result = rgx.Replace(temp, replace);
                }

                //StreamWriter
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(directory + "\\" + fiArray[i].ToString()))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean, that `tempNameNoExtens` contains something like `ABC(5)`?

Comment: yea well its getting the file names so Template - Copy (2), and Template - Copy (5) something like that..

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for a straight string replace like this.  `result = temp.Replace(" " + tempNameNoExtens, " [dbo].[" + tempNameNoExtens + "]");` should be just fine.

Comment: i had to replace 5/6 words with the 1 word having a (') in front, so i don't think that way would work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `Escape` the characters when building a regex pattern:

```
string pattern = "\\s" + Regex.Escape(tempNameNoExtens);
```